# Unable to align certain elements in a website layout I designed. Beginner at coding

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner at coding and I was stuck at a silly issue. I'm unable to align content according to the UI Design. If anybody would be kind enough to help that would be awesome.  Here are the image references [Finished UI Protoype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLRyt.jpg)  [Unfinished Website Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtxST.jpg).

Please find my HTML code below.

Index.html

```
 <a href="#" class="secondary-cta">
    <span>Spring '23 Collection</span>
    <svg width="31" height="23" viewBox="0 0 31 23" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M30.0221 12.5978C30.6284 12.0333 30.6623 11.0842 30.0978 10.4779L20.8987 0.597304C20.3342 -0.00901737 19.385 -0.0429153 18.7787 0.521591C18.1724 1.0861 18.1385 2.03524 18.703 2.64156L26.88 11.4243L18.0973 19.6013C17.491 20.1658 17.4571 21.115 18.0216 21.7213C18.5861 22.3276 19.5352 22.3615 20.1416 21.797L30.0221 12.5978ZM0.946463 11.999L28.9465 12.999L29.0535 10.001L1.05354 9.00096L0.946463 11.999Z" fill="black"/>
</svg >                 
</a>
```

Comment: Please put your code into the question - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

you have not given the link to the html code thats the name of the code.
if you want to center text try
text-align: center;
if you want to center an image or input box try, putting an id and center by doing
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).